# jQuery $.Ajax taking to long to respond

Tags: jquery

I have a simple function that handles submission of row data (one submission per loop).
I will not go into to much detail for what the function is mainly used for but a here is a short summary:
I ahve a lot of data that I loop through and on every loop I call `upload()` function that has an ajax function. Ajax submits the data as a post and then on success calls `insert()` function that continues trhough the loop and calls `upload()` again untill all the data is processed.

```
upload: function( data ){
    var obj = this;
    if( data.post_code && data.post_code.length > 0 ){
        if( ajax_insert ){
            ajax_insert.abort();
        }

        try{
            ajax_insert = $.ajax({
                type    : 'POST',
                url     : '/submission/my-function?ajax',
                data    : $.param( data ),
                success : function( response ) {
                    obj.insert();
                },
                error: function(msg){
                    setInterval(function(){
                        obj.insert();
                    }, 2000);
                }
            });
        }catch(err){
            ajax_insert.abort();
            obj.insert();
        }
    }else{
        this.insert();
    }
}
```

The problem that some clients experience is a stop of submission after some time (some after 60 submits some after 100+). I am not sure if this is because of a slow internet connection but what I noticed using the console on firebug is that when the submission stops in the console it is still showing that Ajax is trying su submit but never completes. And there are no javascript errors shown.

Is there a way to pick up if Ajax is taking to long to complete a submission (lets say it's stuck for almost 5min) and use the `.abort()` to try again?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use..

```
  timeout: 10000, //time in milliseconds.
```

This would at least catch a stalled script.

Comment: Hi Maxum, I tried the timeout and for some reason the client started experiencing even more issue because of that. The issue that the ajax submit gets stuck was resolved but for some reason it started to abord almost every submission after that and it escalated untill the browser crashed. I put in another fix (a retry button) that will force the current ajax submit to stop and try again. Thanks for the help.

Comment: if there wont be any more suggestions I will accept your answer as a correct answer because it did resolve the issue of ajax submission being stuck but the issues that occured after that are not related to my requested question.